# Can I apply AdaBoost on Random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I know the Random forest is a bagging technique. But what if my random forest overfits on a dataset, so I reduce the depth of the decision tree and now it underfitting. In this scenario, can I take the underfitted random forest with little depth and try to boost it?

Comment: You could do this, but it's probably simpler to keep the deeper trees and grow many more of them.

Comment: If you want to use a boosted tree model with row- or column-wise subsampling, this can be achieved using certain features of `lightgbm` or `xgboost`.